# wrong email is saved in the database in Django

Tags: django

I am working on a project where users have to signup first to use this application. I attached the signup code below.

views.py

```
# Create your views here.
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST) # post request is gonna contain data in the message body and validate that form data
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}. You are now able to log in.')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm() # display a blank form
    return render(request, 'users/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

```
{% extends 'users/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <section id="formHolder">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Brand Box -->
            <div class="col-sm-6 brand">
                <a href="#" class="logo">Bookstagram <span>.</span></a>
                <div class="heading">
                    <h3>Bookstagram</h3>
                    <p>Show Off Your Bookish Aestheics</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <!-- Form Box -->
            <div class="col-sm-6 form">
                <!-- Signup Form -->
                <div class="login form-peice">
                    <form class="login-form" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            {{ form|crispy }}
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="CTA">
                            <input type="submit" value="Signup Now" id="submit">
                            <a href="{% url 'login' %}">I have an account</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div><!-- End Signup Form -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

if I give a wrong email such as "cindrella@gmail.c" or "cindrella@g.com", the system saves the user details in the database and he can then login with that credentials. But the email is not correct. So, how can I signup with an correct email? If the email is wrong, the system is supposed to show incorrect email. Therefore, user details will not be stored in the database.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "wrong" email?  What is wrong with `cindrella@g.com`?  Surely you are not expecting that everyone in the world has a `gmail.com` address?

Comment: as people can only create account with gmail, yahoo and hotmail. Therefore, I was thinking it is wrong. Also ```gmail.co``` is wrong email format right? because .com is the correct one. @JohnGordon

Comment: _people can only create account with gmail, yahoo and hotmail_ Okay, so check for those email addresses in the form validation, and throw a validation error if the address is wrong.

Comment: I have already checked the form validation with this ```form.is_valid()```. but this is not working for the correct email format. Can you show me how to cehck for those email addresses in the form validation and throw error if address is wrong? @JohnGordon

Comment: Add a `clean_username()` function to the form that specifically checks if the username field ends in "@gmail.com", "@yahoo.com", etc.  Here's an example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use django's built in 'EmailValidator' and check for the email domain as below. Here's the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/validators/) for more info.

```py
#form.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.core.validators import EmailValidator
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(validators=[EmailValidator()])

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        # Check if the email is valid
        email_validator = EmailValidator()
        try:
            email_validator(email)
        except ValidationError:
            raise ValidationError('Invalid email.')

        # Check if the email domain is allowed
        allowed_domains = ['gmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'hotmail.com']
        email_domain = email.split('@')[-1]
        if email_domain not in allowed_domains:
            raise ValidationError(f'Email domain must be one of the following: {", ".join(allowed_domains)}.')

        return email
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?  They wanted to specifically check that the email address is at hotmail, gmail, or yahoo.  This code does not do that.

Comment: Misunderstood the question and corrected my answer.